# Half way cross-compilation leveraging LLVM - Compile faster on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, clang, llvm, raspberry-pi

The Raspberry Pi takes a lot of time to compile C code.
I want to accelerate that compilation. But I get a compilation error.

To do that, and because I already code on my PC, I want to use my PC, I would like to use LLVM (shipped with cygwin) to produce an LLVM assembly language version of the executable. And then, send it to the Raspberry Pi for final conversion to a native (ARM) executable.

I am hoping to get to a executable a lot faster because I could compile to LLVM language my code in parallel on my multi-core machine before linking (llvm-link).
The last step on the Raspberry Pi itself, translating LLVM language to executable binary would be short, I hope.

Let's take an example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("0");
  return 0;
}
```

Then on my PC, I run

`clang a.c -emit-llvm -S`

This produces a file called **a.s** an LLVM language version of the .c file

And then, I send **a.s** to the Raspberry Pi and run on it the command `llc -filetype=obj a.s` to generate **a.s.o** an object file.

But when I want to create an executable on the Rasp Pi from this object file, I get an error:

```
clang a.s.o -o a.out
/usr/bin/ld: error: a.out uses VFP register arguments, a.s.o does not
/usr/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file a.s.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried using the following flags `-marm -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp` with **clang** on the last step but that fails with the same errors.
Do you know how to solve this error or have some suggestions that would help me using LLVM to speed up my compilation process?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330110/llvm-build-options-for-arm-raspberrypi - you can use the same technique for your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LLVM IR is not portable. It contains all sorts of things spercific to your machine (is an int 32 bit or 64 bit, sizeof and calling conventions). In order to get this to work you need to pass clang arguments as if you are doing a full cross compile. At which point because clang is a full cross compilier you might as well just compile object files.

So compile object files with `clang -target armv6-linux-gnueabi -integrated-as -marm -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpu -c` on your pc then link on the pi using ld.

Edit:

Since you mention the cygwin clang integrated assembler doesn't work the best option is to output arm assembly with: `clang -target armv6-linux-gnueabi -marm -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpu -S`

Comment: Hi having tried with clang on cygwin, I had to add the option -S. This is to generate the assembly instead of trying creating an object file which fails (/tmp/a-QlWm4u.s:1: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.syntax'). Also, on cygwin, -mfpu=vfpu does not seem to be supported. 
Having done that I was successfully able to compile the assembly on the Pi.

Comment: The point pf this solution is to generate object files not assembly. Offload more work to the pc without any additional flags or software.

Comment: I just edited my comment, please have a look. Do you know how to "link" assembly files without compiling ? This is to avoid having errors with cygwin clang.

Comment: Ok, looks like the Cygwin clang has that good an integrated assembler for arm, in which case outputting arm assembly is probably the best option.

Comment: Or it may be because I missspelt integrated so clang was using the system assembler not the integrated arm one.

Comment: You also need to use the right sysroot (e.g., a copy of your raspbian installation).

Comment: To be honest, I had to patch the cygwin header /usr/include/machine/_default_types.h because of defines errors (see: https://sourceware.org/ml/newlib/2014/msg00082.html)

Comment: Yes we do need the sys-root for headers but not binaries or libraries. Shouldn't be too difficult to just copy over the required headers as there just text files.

Comment: How did you know about the appropriate compiler options to use?

Comment: I've been doing pi cross-compiling recently. On a project that uses code generators so I had to work out the flags myself because some things had to be compiled natively and some for the pi.

Comment: I had to copy /usr/lib,  /usr/local, /usr/include/ and /lib to be able to use it as a sysroot. I had missing headers.