# Crosscompile program for LLVM for ARMv6 on Ubuntu 32bit i686

Tags: c++, arm, raspberry-pi, llvm

I'm near to frustration ;-). Since more than a week I try to crosscompile on my ubunutu 12.04 box i686 Linux machine for a ARMv6 machine (arm1176jzf-s - known as Raspberry Pi) an own developed program with LLVM 3.4.2.
After days I was able to compile and link successfully. But as I've tried to execute my code on the Raspberry Pi I only received a memory access error. It has turned out that a segmentation fault is raised. I have analyzed it with gdb. Please refer please to the enclosed picture.

[image: The executable on ARM analyzed with gdb].

Basically I have done the following:

```
I build the C and C++ files: @echo 'Compiling' $(1).$(2); cd $(BIN); $(4) -c $(COMPILE_FLAGS) ../$(3)/$(1).$(2) -o $(1).o $(LLVM_CONFIG_COMPILE); cd .. 
I llvm-linked it: cd $(BIN); $(LINK) -o tl.bc $(1)
Then I called the system compiler: cd $(BIN); $(LLC)  $(LINKER_FLAGS) -filetype=obj tl.thumb.opt.bc -o tl.thumb.opt.o 
 And I called the linker, i.e. the arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: $(LD) -o bin/tl bin/tl.thumb.opt.o $(LINK_OPTION) $(THREAD_LIB_DIR) $(call INFLATE_config)
`test -f bin/tl` && echo 'Make was successful. Find Turbo Lisp in folder' $(BIN)
```

Take a look at my console output for my make file:

Building Turbo Lisp 0.01 for machine i686 with operating system GNU/Linux

COMPILE_FLAGS used:

```
-fno-strict-aliasing -emit-llvm -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -mfpu=vfpv3-d16    -mthumb -target arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/4.6 -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/4.6/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/include -I/usr/local/lib/LLVM_ARM/BOOST -ccc-gcc-name arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc

Compiling precedence.cpp
Compiling util.cpp
Compiling ast.cpp
Compiling abstractParser.cpp
Compiling metaparser.cpp
Compiling parserLisp.cpp
Compiling parserToy.cpp
Compiling preconfiguredLanguages.cpp
Compiling handler.cpp
Compiling helper.cpp
Compiling lexer.cpp
Compiling config_reader.cpp
Compiling tl.cpp
Compiling external_functions.c
Compiling error_util.cpp
```

Building binary code from:

```
tl.o preconfiguredLanguages.o handler.o external_functions.o abstractParser.o parserLisp.o parserToy.o metaparser.o ast.o helper.o util.o error_util.o config_reader.o lexer.o precedence.o
```

Linking...

```
cd bin; <myhome>/projects/llvm-3.4.2.src/buildARMCompileX86/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-link -o tl.bc tl.o preconfiguredLanguages.o handler.o external_functions.o abstractParser.o parserLisp.o parserToy.o metaparser.o ast.o helper.o util.o error_util.o config_reader.o lexer.o precedence.o
```

Optimizing...

```
cd bin; <myhome>/projects/llvm-3.4.2.src/buildARMCompileX86/Release+Asserts/bin/opt tl.bc -o tl.thumb.opt.bc -float-abi=hard -std-compile-opts
```

System compiling...

```
cd bin; <myhome>/projects/llvm-3.4.2.src/buildARMCompileX86/Release+Asserts/bin/llc   -float-abi=hard -march=arm -mtriple=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -filetype=obj tl.thumb.opt.bc -o tl.thumb.opt.o
```

...And finally linking to native...

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -o bin/tl bin/tl.thumb.opt.o -v -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/local/lib/LLVM_ARM/BOOST -L/usr/local/lib/LLVM_ARM -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/local/lib/LLVM_ARM/BOOST -L/usr/local/lib/LLVM_ARM -lz -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lm -lLLVMInterpreter -lLLVMMCJIT -lLLVMJIT -lLLVMRuntimeDyld -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMARMDisassembler -lLLVMARMCodeGen -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMObjCARCOpts -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMARMAsmParser -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMARMDesc -lLLVMARMInfo -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMCore -lLLVMARMAsmPrinter -lLLVMMC -lLLVMObject -lLLVMSupport -lpthread -ldl

`test -f bin/tl` && echo 'Make was successful. Find Turbo Lisp in folder' bin
Make was successful. Find Turbo Lisp in folder bin
```

It would be very nice, if anybody knowing much more about compiling for ARM could share his knowledge with me and direct me to the point I made so wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330110/llvm-build-options-for-arm-raspberrypi/15350488#15350488

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I did it!

Maybe many of you are more interested in gcc than in LLVM and clang. But I think the issue here is more **generally**, than specific to LLVM. After I tried to compile LLVM and clang for ARM I ran another gdb session. It has turned out that glibc has different versions on my raspberry (2.13) and on my ubuntu (2.15). So I copied the libc from my ARM to my ubuntu system, but this didn't worked. I received messages from my gdb like "invalid machine instruction". This has caused me to check a bit more thoroughly the configure.log file of the clang build.

And, yes, the gcc cross compiler of ubuntu is simply compiled for an **ARMv7** architecture, but the Raspberry is of ARMv6 (with ARM11 chip set). 
So, the next point was to build my own gcc toolchain. First I tried to build my binutils, which allegedly was successful. Then I was heading to compile gcc linaro. And this has cost me days. At the end I hadn't achieved this mission. Either some include files were missing or linker issues have stopped me.

But I had the brilliant idea to make some more research, especially with keywords for the rasperry pi. And this has then pushed me back on track as I found crosstool-ng. What a great tool! You only need to configure in a kind of a menu which platform you like to address and then this tool downloads all your required files for a complete toolchain and installs it. Great! As I made this hurdle, it was pretty easy to build LLVM and clang. 
The only point everybody needs to manage is to upgrade the Raspberry Pi, i.e. upgrade libc and libstdc++ by apt-get with the "testing" stage.

Feel free to ignore it or just check it out if you have also troubles to build up a correct gcc toolchain: [Tutorial to setup crosstool-ng for RPi](http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/426)

Answer (score 0):

Would like to comment but can't due to low "reputaion"...

Since you are "near to frustration" I would suggest trying gcc instead of LLVM because then it's likely easier to get help.